# General code completion framework written in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, parsing, code-completion

Is there any framework written in C/C++/C++11 for writing code completion tools?
Or maybe are there some libraries that allow code completion for Java or C++ (also written in C++?).
I'm writing my custom IDE in C++ for Java (and not only Java) development and I want to add code completion support to it the best possible way, without reinventing the weel ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang_complete is a plugin for vim for accurately completing C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++ code: https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/
It uses clang - an open source C++ compiler written in C++ for doing the job. I guess you may find it useful.

Comment: thank you, yours response is great and my question was not good enough (I was looking for something more specific). Please take a look at new, more precise question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601312/syntactic-and-semantic-code-completion-framework-written-in-c.