# syntactic and semantic code completion framework written in C++

Tags: java, c++, parsing, intellisense, code-completion

This question is more precise than my previous one: [General code completion framework written in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595747/general-code-completion-framework-written-in-c-c/13595826#13595826). I did not specify it enough to get answers I really need.

I want to add to my IDE the "Intellisense" code completion. I would love to have a library in C/C++/C++11, that could work as syntactic and symantic code completion tool and be general, not single language specific (I want to write completion for Java, C++ and in the future for C#, Python and Javascript).
It would be good if this solution would not be one language centric - it should be general and scalable across languages.

(I have found something called [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/intellisense.shtml), which according to its webiste is something I would like to have, but its written in Lisp, not C++.)

Could you please help me with finding the good solution?

Comment: If you want good context-aware C++ intellisense, you should probably take a look at clang. I think at least latest versions of Qt Creator use clang for parsing C(++) source files, to provide proper intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for Netbeans, Eclipse and IntelliJ is open source these support cross platform "intelisense" code completion.  IMHO IntelliJ's is the best.  I suspect C++ is not the most elegant language to describe this capability.

Comment: But as far as I know, all these solutions ar written in Java, not C++?

Comment: Correct, but you can use the code and inspiration for your solution. Or call them from C++.

Comment: You are right, if there will be no "ready" solution I will do it like this, but I hope there will be some "native" libraries supporting this task